# replace string with object in php

Tags: php, xml

I am attempting to convert a HTML input into a XML output with PHP I have been using the XML Writer functions to create the XML output but i am looking to modify a string example string

```
this is some text <span class"bold">this is bold text</span> normal text
```

but need the output to be

```
this is some text
    <text:span text:style-name="bold">this is bold text</text:span>
normal text
```

I am relitivly new to the Object PHP so unsure of the best way to do this.

the code I have sofar follows

```
$xml->startElement("office:body");
    $xml->startElement("office:text");
         preg_match_all("/\<p\>(.*)\<\/p\>/",$data['Content'],$matches);
         foreach ($matches[1] as $paragraph)
         {
             $xml->startElement("text:p");
                  $xml->text("$paragraph");
             $xml->endElement();
         }
     $xml->endElement();
$xml->endElement();
```

This shows how i have devided the string into paragraphs but now i am looking to get any adational formating the content of $paragraph should contain the string first mentioned and want the output mentioned. any help would be greatful

Vip32

Comment: The output is not valid xml, it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Please show the code in question even if it does not yet full work. you likely want to add a child element with namespace prefixes, see http://php.net/function.xmlwriter-start-element-ns

Comment: this is a snipit of the files. i am attempting to convert HTML to ODT document which uses XML files compressed, i am attempting to create the Content.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first simplehtmldom library to read html data first:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/